# Using Xcode Version 6.4 (6E7)

Tags: layout, autolayout, view, constraints

I'm trying to learn how to create apps by following the Standford swift class where the professor uses the constraint icons to position the UI objects on the views. In the course, the storyboard page shows the constraint icons  at the bottom of the storyboard page.

I just download and started using Xcode Version 6.4 (6E7) and while creating the UI in a viewController I noticed the constraint buttons at the end of page are missing or not available. is there a way to get access to them thru the Xcode menus.

Where are they now?

Comment: I just downloaded 6.4 beta 2 (6E14).  The constraint buttons are there at the bottom of the page as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints buttons usually do not show up if you don't have auto layout enabled for the storyboard or XIB. The easiest way to check is to open the storyboard in Interface Builder, switch to the File Inspector (ALT+Command+1) and then check the Interface Builder Document section. There should be a checkbox for "Use Auto Layout". Is it checked?

Comment: no the **Use Auto Layout** wasn't checked, checking it solved my issue; thank you..